# How to delete email from the server?

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

I am using Outlook version 16.16.2 (180910) as a communication program for my company's email address.

When I delete messages from my Inbox, the action done locally on my Mac, but I need it to be deleted from the company's server too.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using POP or IMAP? Outlook is IMAP 'behind the scenes' but can be used as though it was POP. With POP, local actions don't affect the remote storage.

Comment: I don't have or use Microsoft products anymore; however I found plenty of examples searching Google and it is in the account settings to remove email from server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setup for POP (which it appears you are) then check this out...

That preference would be in Outlook menu >  Preferences > Accounts > your POP account > Advanced > Server tab.
Uncheck the option “Leave a copy of each message on server”.